# How to run Docker Container in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, docker, spyder

I have docker image/container with virtual environment and currently I'm able to run it in VS Code using Remote Development extension. Is it possible to do something similar in Spyder?

**EDIT:**
That's what I've done so far:

My dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update && apt install  openssh-server sudo -y

# Create a user “sshuser” and group “sshgroup”
RUN groupadd sshgroup && useradd -ms /bin/bash -g sshgroup sshuser
# Create sshuser directory in home
RUN mkdir -p /home/sshuser/.ssh
# Copy the ssh public key in the authorized_keys file. The idkey.pub below is a public key file you get from ssh-keygen. They are under ~/.ssh directory by default.
COPY key.pub /home/sshuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
# change ownership of the key file. 
RUN chown sshuser:sshgroup /home/sshuser/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 /home/sshuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
# Start SSH service
RUN service ssh start
# Expose docker port 22
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]

USER root
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN pip install jupyter
RUN pip install spyder-kernels
```

Then in powershell I typed:

```
docker run -d -p 2022:22 sshubuntu
ssh -i key sshuser@localhost -p 2022 # (here I typed my password and successfully logged into container)
jupyter --runtime-dir # /home/sshuser/.local/share/jupyter/runtime
python3 -m spyder_kernels.console
```

Now using another instance of powershell I copied `json` to local machine:

```
docker cp 21ff6e147a2d:/home/sshuser/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-24.json .
```

The file is:

```
{
  "shell_port": 46227,
  "iopub_port": 34519,
  "stdin_port": 43075,
  "control_port": 38781,
  "hb_port": 44761,
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "key": "1c925c4a-983896e82c953e4fccb7ce90",
  "transport": "tcp",
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "kernel_name": ""
}
```

Finally I opened Spyder and typed the following:

[Spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSFd0.png)

The results is that "Connecting to kernel..." appears and nothing happenes. What am I doing wrong that it doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The best you can do at the moment is starting a kernel in the container and connect to it from Spyder through SSH. The instructions for that are described [here](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-a-remote-kernel).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link to documentation. I tried to follow it but without succes. Are you able to tell me what am I doing wrong (see updated question)

Comment: You need to be sure that the Spyder and Spyder-kernels versions are in sync. That's described [here](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/common-illnesses.html#spyder-kernels-not-installed-incompatible).

Comment: I have spyder 5.3.1 and spyder-kernels 2.3.1. Do you have any other guesses what can be wrong with my procedure?

Comment: You also need to open all ports listed in the json file that is used by Spyder to connect to the remote kernel. As far as I can tell, you're only exposing port 22, which is not enough.